# What's the purpose of inactive "apply to answers too" checkbox on mod menu if the item text already refers to answers only?

Tags: feature-request, support, moderator-tools, community-wiki

If there are answers with wiki status, the mod menu for a question contains the following item (Remove wiki from answers):

> [image]

<sup>* text autotranslated from Russian to English</sup>

What's the purpose of inactive checkbox "Apply to answers too" when the radio item already states about "answers" (Remove wiki from **answers**)?

Would it be better to just remove the checkbox at all since there's already a condition which changes the radio item text. It will prevent confusing about that checkbox existance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option changes depending on the wiki status of the question. If the question itself is community wiki, you have the option of removing wiki status from just the question, and you are able to untick the "answers too" option:

[image: The moderator actions post popup, with "Remove wiki from question (and optionally from answers)" selected. An "Apply to answers too" checkbox is ticked.]

If the question is not community wiki, but at least one answer is, this option on the question will de-wiki all answers. Since the question itself isn't wiki, and can't have its wiki status removed, the checkbox to only apply the action to the question is disabled.

If you want to remove the wiki status of a single answer but not all of the answers to a question, you can do that from the mod menu of that specific post.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But if there's already conditions to show different text on radio item, it would be better to remove checkbox at all for case where the question isn't wiki. So for me it still looks like a bug. Because checkbox existing here is confusing.

Comment: I disagree, @αλεχολυτ - having the greyed-out option acts as a reminder that the option does exist in some cases. Seeing the option could hint to a moderator that they can remove the status from the question and answers simultaneously by starting with the question. I don't think either is "wrong", though... just different UX options.

Comment: @Catija but I already started from the question